# How to set up server with Azure app services to take POST requests

Tags: reactjs, azure, express, azure-web-app-service, serverless

I can't seem to get the Azure app services to accept any requests other than GET. I know the express app is running because I point the '/' URL default to look at server/index.js (my express server) and can alter the behavior (I redirect to another path). But when I try to hit another endpoint that exists on the server, it gives me a 404.

My configurations are setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" />
    <handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="server/index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^server/index.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="server/index.js" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Express server code:

```
const express = require('express');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

//initialize express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}./../dist`));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './../dist/index.html'), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
});

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

    /* Login logic here*/
});

/* * Server * */
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a really obscure issue around security. Update the web.config to include the following:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <verbs allowUnlisted="true">
      <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true" />
    </verbs>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering